# Text alignment within tikzfigure environment of the tikzposter class

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzposter

For my poster I am using the `tikzfigure` environment within `tikzposter` to add figures. It works fine, but I want to have the figure captions justified or left aligned instead of centered.

I have tried `\justify` or `\begin{flushleft} ... \end{flushleft}` within the caption, changing the `tikzposter` class file but it does not work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape, margin=0mm, innermargin=50mm,
 blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=30mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter} 
\geometry{paperwidth=100cm,paperheight=197cm} 
\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-2\TP@innermargin}
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-2\TP@innermargin}
\makeatother
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofon 
% Commands
\newcommand{\bs}{\textbackslash}   
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{{\bf \color{red}#1}}   
\usetheme{Simple}
\usebackgroundstyle{Empty}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

 \begin{columns}%blocks will be placed into columns

                \column{.5}
                    \block{someblock1}{
                     \begin{tikzfigure}[\justify CAPTION HERE]
                     \includegraphics[width=0.40\colwidth] {images/someimage1.pdf}
                     \end{tikzfigure}      
            }

                \column{.5}
                    \block{someblock2}{
                    \begin{flushleft}
                    \begin{tikzfigure}[CAPTION HERE]
                    \includegraphics[width=0.40\colwidth] {images/someimage2.pdf}
                    \end{tikzfigure} 
                    \end{flushleft}
            }

 \end{columns}

 \end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind to include some Minimal Working Example to play with. Please from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and including all packages related with your problem. It will be easy to help you. Thanks.

Comment: My apologies. I have added a MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First version:

Put this in your preamble. Here the caption is aligned to the left starting with the figure:

```
\renewenvironment{tikzfigure}[1][]{
  \def \rememberparameter{#1}
  \vspace{10pt}
  \refstepcounter{figurecounter}
  \begin{center}
  \tabular{l}
  }{
    \ifx\rememberparameter\@empty
    \else %nothing
    \\[10pt]
    {\small Fig.~\thefigurecounter: \rememberparameter }
    \fi
  \endtabular
  \end{center}
}
```

[image]

Second version:

Here the caption is aligned totally to the left.

```
\renewenvironment{tikzfigure}[1][]{
  \def \rememberparameter{#1}
  \vspace{10pt}
  \refstepcounter{figurecounter}
  \begin{center}
  }{
    \ifx\rememberparameter\@empty
    \else %nothing
    \\[10pt]
    {\small Fig.~\thefigurecounter: \rememberparameter \hfill \mbox{}}
    \fi
  \end{center}
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape, margin=0mm, innermargin=50mm,
 blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=30mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=100cm,paperheight=197cm}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-2\TP@innermargin}
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-2\TP@innermargin}
\makeatother
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofon
% Commands
\newcommand{\bs}{\textbackslash}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{{\bf \color{red}#1}}
\usetheme{Simple}
\usebackgroundstyle{Empty}

%\renewenvironment{tikzfigure}[1][]{
%  \def \rememberparameter{#1}
%  \vspace{10pt}
%  \refstepcounter{figurecounter}
%  \begin{center}
%  \tabular{l}
%  }{
%    \ifx\rememberparameter\@empty
%    \else %nothing
%    \\[10pt]
%    {\small Fig.~\thefigurecounter: \rememberparameter }
%    \fi
%  \endtabular
%  \end{center}
%}

\renewenvironment{tikzfigure}[1][]{
  \def \rememberparameter{#1}
  \vspace{10pt}
  \refstepcounter{figurecounter}
  \begin{center}
  }{
    \ifx\rememberparameter\@empty
    \else %nothing
    \\[10pt]
    {\small Fig.~\thefigurecounter: \rememberparameter \hfill \mbox{}}
    \fi
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

 \begin{columns}%blocks will be placed into columns

                \column{.5}
                    \block{someblock1}{
                     \begin{tikzfigure}[CAPTION HERE]
                     \includegraphics[width=0.40\colwidth] {example-image}
                     \end{tikzfigure}
            }

                \column{.5}
                    \block{someblock2}{
                    \begin{flushleft}
                    \begin{tikzfigure}[CAPTION HERE]
                    \includegraphics[width=0.40\colwidth] {example-image}
                    \end{tikzfigure}
                    \end{flushleft}
            }

 \end{columns}

 \end{document}
```

If you want to do it on per figure basis you may use a `\parbox`

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape, margin=0mm, innermargin=50mm,
 blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=30mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=100cm,paperheight=197cm}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-2\TP@innermargin}
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-2\TP@innermargin}
\makeatother
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofon
% Commands
\newcommand{\bs}{\textbackslash}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{{\bf \color{red}#1}}
\usetheme{Simple}
\usebackgroundstyle{Empty}


\begin{document}

    \maketitle

 \begin{columns}%blocks will be placed into columns

                \column{.5}
                    \block{someblock1}{
                     \begin{tikzfigure}[{\parbox[t]{0.39\colwidth}{CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE }}]
                     \includegraphics[width=0.40\colwidth] {example-image}
                     \end{tikzfigure}
            }

                \column{.5}
                    \block{someblock2}{
                    \begin{flushleft}
                    \begin{tikzfigure}[CAPTION HERE]
                    \includegraphics[width=0.40\colwidth] {example-image}
                    \end{tikzfigure}
                    \end{flushleft}
            }

 \end{columns}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that an extra pair of braces is needed surroung the `\parbox` in

```
\begin{tikzfigure}[{\parbox[t]{0.39\colwidth}{CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE CAPTION HERE }}]
```

Comment: Thanks!But now I the lines don't break according to the column end. How do I fix that?

Comment: @jon86 In which version do you want the modification for breaking lines?

Comment: Kumar. The first version. Is it maybe also possible to do this for each caption seperately?

Comment: @jon86 Instead of `l` column, use `p` column with a width equal to the width of the figure (here `0.4\colwidth`. You have to do it manually).

Comment: @jon86 line break and per figure basis added now.